# Continuous embedding of fractional Sobolev spaces in $L^q$ for $q<p^*$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)\to L^q(\mathbb R^N)$ continuously for every $p\leq q\leq p^*$ where $p^*=\frac{Np}{N-p}$. This fact is proved in Theorem 6.5 of the following article:
[Hitchhiker’s guide
to the fractional Sobolev spaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345)
 ([pdf link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf))

for $q=p^*$, i.e. for every $f\in W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, one has
$$
||f||_{L^{p^*}(\mathbb{R}^N)}^p\leq C\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{N+sp}}\,dx dy.
$$

Now, the case of $q\in[p,p^*)$ "follows by Holder inequality" is written in the proof of Theorem 6.5 in the above article. I do not get how it follows from Holder inequality, since $\mathbb{R}^N$ is an unbounded domain. Can somebody kindly help, thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\|f\|_{W^{s,p}} = \|f\|_{L^{p}} +\|f\|_{\dot W^{s,p}}$ where the last term is the right-hand side of your inequality.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Yes, but how to dominate $||f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)}$ by the r.h.s of our required inequality? I am unable to see it. It is only proven for $p*$

Comment: The $p$ norm is controlled by the $s,p$ norm as it is part of it. So, you just need to control the $q$ norm by the $p$ norm and the $p^*$ norm. Then the $p^*$ norm is controlled by your r.h.s, so everything is controlled by the $W^{s,p}$.

Comment: If your question was: " can we control the $L^p$ norm by the r.h.s", then the answer is no. As for classical Sobolev spaces, this follows by scaling.

Comment: Thank you. But how do you control the q norm by the W^{s,p} norm? I understand it holds for $q=p$ and $q=p*$. But worried hot to get for $q\in(p,p*)$. As it is mentioned in the link, Holder inequality would give the same. But how does it follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\|f\|_{W^{s,p}} := \|f\|_{L^p} + \|f\|_{\dot{W}^{s,p}}$, where $$\|f\|_{\dot{W}^{s,p}} := \iint_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+sp}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

By Hölder's inequality,
$$
\|f\|_{L^q} ≤ \|f\|_{L^p}^{\theta} \|f\|_{L^{p^*}}^{1-\theta}
$$
with $θ = \frac{1/q - 1/p}{1/p^* - 1/p}$. As you write, by the Fractional Sobolev embedding,
$$
\|f\|_{L^{p^*}} ≤ C_{d,s,p}\,\|f\|_{\dot{W}^{s,p}}
$$
and so
$$
\|f\|_{L^q} ≤ C_{d,s,p}^{1-\theta}\,\|f\|_{L^p}^{\theta} \|f\|_{\dot{W}^{s,p}}^{1-\theta}.
$$
(This is sometimes called a Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev interpolation type inequality). Now by Young's inequality for the product, for any $a,b$ positive, it holds $a^{\theta}b^{1-\theta}≤ θ a + (1-\theta)b$, and so $a^{\theta}b^{1-\theta} ≤ a+b$. Therefore
$$
\|f\|_{L^q} ≤ C_{d,s,p}^{1-\theta}\,(\|f\|_{L^p} +\|f\|_{\dot{W}^{s,p}}) = C_{d,s,p}^{1-\theta}\,\|f\|_{{W}^{s,p}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much.